# Angular - ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: angular

I am trying to get data(JSON) from the server and display on the web only after I click on the button.
After the first click, I get an error:

```
core.js:4352 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'imie' of undefined
    at HttpTestComponent.get (http-test.component.ts:28)
    at HttpTestComponent_Template_button_click_6_listener (http-test.component.html:6)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:15214)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:15249)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:582)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27474)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:480)
```

After the Second click it's works. Where is the problem?

service  file

```
export class LoginService {
      private url = 'http://localhost:8080/test';
      constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
      }
          getTest(): Observable<IPerson>{
    
        return this.http.get<IPerson>(this.url);
        
      }
    }
```

component file

```
export class HttpTestComponent implements OnInit{

  private record:IPerson;
  name: string="aaaa";
  surname: string="bbbb";
  constructor(private loginService: LoginService) { }

  get(){
       this.loginService.getTest().subscribe((data:IPerson)=>this.record = data);
        this.name = this.record.imie;
        this.surname = this.record.nazwisko;
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

IPerson class

```
export class IPerson implements Person{

  _imie: string;
  _nazwisko: string;

  get imie(): string {
    return this._imie;
  }

  get nazwisko(): string {
    return this._nazwisko;
  }
}
```

template

```
<p>http-test works!</p>

<h1>{{name}}</h1>
<h1>{{surname}}</h1>

<button class="btn-large" (click)="get()">Dane</button>
```

Comment: Check if `record` is present by doing this `this.name = this.record?.imie;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because getTest() is async, you need to fetch props inside subscriber, otherwise record is undefined

```
get(){
 this.loginService.getTest().subscribe((data:IPerson)=> {
  this.record = data;
  this.name = this.record.imie;
  this.surname = this.record.nazwisko;
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in this line;

```
this.loginService.getTest().subscribe((data:IPerson)=>this.record = data);
```

Now, `.subscribe` is a method of [Observable](https://angular.io/guide/observables) type, and quoting here;

Observables are declarative—that is, you define a function for publishing values, **but it is not executed until** a consumer subscribes to it. The subscribed consumer then receives notifications until the function completes, or until they unsubscribe.

Based on your code, it seems that your Observable is to perform http GET request on `user`.
Now, moving to the next line;

```
this.name = this.record.imie;
```

This is the code that throws the error, because when this line gets executed `this.record` is still `undefined` since you assign `this.record` in the observable callback.

One of the approach is to wrap the code after observable runs your callback;

```
this.loginService.getTest().subscribe((data:IPerson) => 
    this.record = data;
    this.name = this.record.imie;
    this.surname = this.record.nazwisko;
);
```

Other approach is to encapsulate your function with `async/await`, based on your code - perhaps it would be like (Following code is not tested);

```
// In your service
getTest() : Promise<any> {
   const response = this.http.get(this.url).toPromise();
   return response.json(); // Not sure if this is needed.
}

// Component
async getUser() {
   const record = await this.loginService.getTest();
   this.name = record.imie;
   this.surname = record.nazwisko;
}
```